# Guidelines to implement custom RoleStorageProvider for keycloak

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-spi

I am looking to implement a custom Keycloak SPI (Keycloak 22.0.3) for providing roles from our database.

I tried to extend `org.keycloak.storage.role.RoleStorageProviderFactory` but I cannot see the provider anywhere so that I can enable it.

Can anybody here suggest a solution or a way forward?